# acsses to javascript PDFObject

Tags: javascript, jquery, pdf-generation

I'm using PDFObject for my application :

```
var myPDF = new PDFObject({
    url:myUrl,
    id:"myPDF",
    width:"100%",
    height:"100%",
    pdfOpenParams:{
        navpanes:1,
        statusbar:0,
        toolbar:1,
        view:"FitH",
        pagemode:"bookmarks",
        page:anchor
    }
})

var fullText = functionGettingResults()
```

I want added dinamically `search : fulltext` in pdfOpenParams.

`myPDF.pdfOpenParams.search = fullText` not works

How I can ?

thx

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
var fulltext;

var params = {
    navpanes:1,
    statusbar:0,
    toolbar:1,
    view:"FitH",
    pagemode:"bookmarks",
    page:anchor
}


if(fulltext == functionGettingResults()){
params.search = fulltext;
}

var myPDF = new PDFObject({
    url:pdfUrl,
    id:"myPDF",
    width:"100%",
    height:"100%",
    pdfOpenParams:params
}).embed("div");
```